# Can't Json.Unmarshal to a struct

Tags: json, go, struct, tcp

I've got a situation, where I want to transfer messages with a TCP Connection from one server to another. 
I've created a struct on both servers:

```
type DataTransferObject struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}
```

and with

```
dto := DataTransferObject{
    Name:  "Name",
    Value: name,
}

jsonDTO, _ := json.Marshal(dto)
connection.Write(jsonDTO)
```

I'm sending it to the other server. The server receives a message, but when I try to unmarshal it like this:

```
var MessageData DataTransferObject

        err = json.Unmarshal(message, &MessageData)
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
```

the MessageData struct stays nil. However when I print the message with

```
fmt.Println(string(message))
```

I get a string like this : {"Name":"testname","Value":"testvalue"}

Comment: Your struct tags are invalid. Re-read the documentation. You should have `json:"name"` (with quotes, no spaces).

Comment: @Adrian had that before and changed it now back to json:"name", but didn't change my problem.

Comment: Then the issue is in something you're not showing us, because as described, it works fine: https://play.golang.org/p/Meeg0dEmuIg

Comment: I've edited the code because I've found some mistakes on my own and this is now the acutal code. But still the problem isn't solved.
But now I received an "invalid character '\x00' after top-level value" message but still can print the message with fmt.Println(string(message))

Comment: A friend of mine just figured out that json.marshal and unmarshal to a struct also works before sending the data. Only on the other side of the TCP connection the error appears.

Comment: I'm confused why you have `"Name"` and `"Value"` when printing `string(message)`, yet your json struct tags are `"name"` and `"value"`. I think there is some information you are leaving out. Try giving us a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: @Gavin might have found the problem. Could it be that your struct is defined differently on the two ends of the connection?

Comment: string(message) is just something that I tried to see if there's wrong json in my message. I will post my complete code now.

Comment: @Mad Wombat no the struct is copied/pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem you are encountering is because json.Unmarshal doesn't handle the string termination in the byte array (this actually looks like a bug to me, if it expects a byte array it should know how to deal with it). So when you are allocating a 1024 byte buffer and read into it from connection, you end up with a few characters of data, null byte terminator and whatever garbage the rest of the buffer is. And that confuses json.Unmarshall. It actually throws an error about it and if you didn't ignore your error handling you would see it :)

Public Service Announcement: if something returns an error, you might want to at least print it. You will thank yourself later when shit breaks.

There are a few ways of dealing with it, but it seems that the standard is to use bufio library. Here is a complete, working example sending a JSON record down the TCP connection and de-serializing it into a struct (yes, this code completely ignores all errors)

package main

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "time"
)

type DataTransferObject struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

func server(l net.Listener) {
    for {
        c, _ := l.Accept()
        data, _ := bufio.NewReader(c).ReadBytes(0)
        fmt.Printf("read %v bytes from the server\n", len(data))
        fmt.Println("data: ", string(data))
        var obj DataTransferObject
        err := json.Unmarshal(data, &obj)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Got object %+v\n", obj)
    }
}

func main() {
    l, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    defer l.Close()
    go server(l)
    con, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8080")
    data := []byte(`{"name": "Mad Wombat", "value": "Awesome Go Marsupial"}`)
    count, _ := con.Write(data)
    fmt.Printf("written %v bytes to the server\n", count)
    con.Close()
    time.Sleep(time.Second) // wait for the server to do its thing
}
```

Comment: "Unmarshall actually throws an error about it and if you didn't ignore your error handling you would see it :)"
If the error is: "invalid character '\x00' after top-level value" than I wrote about it in the comment section. Thank you, will try this and reply

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Looks like json.Unmarshal is being hypocritical about it, it expects a byte array, but secretly expects the byte array to be a single, complete string. So when it encounters a null character it throws a hissy fit.

Comment: It actually worked! But now I've got another error which I've got to fix :-D
"read tcp [::1]:4242->[::1]:49634: wsarecv: (...)", but I will figure this out !

Answer (score 1):

The struct in both projects:

```
type DataTransferObject struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}
```

this is the complete code for receiving:

```
/**
* function for receiving a message with data from a client
**/
func (manager *ClientManager) receive(client *Client) {
    for {
        message := make([]byte,1024)
        length, err := client.socketConnection.Read(message)


        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            manager.unregister <- client
            client.socketConnection.Close()
            break
        }

        if length > 0 {
            var MessageData DataTransferObject

            err = json.Unmarshal(message, &MessageData)
            fmt.Println(err.Error())

            if MessageData.Name =="Name"{
                manager.clientAddr[MessageData.Value] = client
                manager.SendData("testMessage", "hello world!")
            }else {
                fmt.Println(string (message))
            }

            manager.broadcast <- message
        }
    }
}
```

this is the complete function for sending data:

```
func StartClient() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Please Insert a name: ")

    for scanner.Scan() {
    name = scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println("Name is now: " + name)
        if len(name) > 0 {
            break;
        }
    }

    if scanner.Err() != nil {

    }

    fmt.Println("Starting client...")
    connection, error := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:4242")

    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println(error)
    }
    client := &Client{socket: connection}
    go client.receive()
    dto := DataTransferObject{
        Name:  "Name",
        Value: name,
    }

    jsonDTO, _ := json.Marshal(dto)
    connection.Write(jsonDTO)

}
```

Comment: hope I didn't mess up any name declarations. Just changed some var names.

Comment: I am deeply confused by this code. Are you trying to read and write on the same end of the connection?

Comment: Where do you listen on port 4242 and accept the incoming connection?

Comment: I can't post my complete project because I've been working for weeks now. That's kind of the problem why it's maybe confusing. 
The first is my Webserver which in his main function is listening on port 4242 for tcp connections (besides the port for the webapplication obviously).
When I get a message I map the client to a name so I can Identify the client later on. For test reasons I'm trying to send a message back to the client which should be able to be found by the name. 
That's basically what's happening.

Comment: @MadWombat also the messages can be send. Sending []byte and receiving it is no problem at all and can be parsed to string. But when it comes to json it doesn't work.  I've read that maybe it's because of the buffersize ? "   message := make([]byte,1024)"

Comment: I experimented a bit. There are a few caveats that I found. It looks like the combination of `make([]byte,1024)` and `string(message)` doesn't work as expected. It results in a string with a null byte in the middle. I will post an answer in a few.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180548/discussion-between-hierarchy-and-mad-wombat).